# Assignment & gradebook error

Tags: moodle

With some courses, I am receiving a dmlwriteexception when trying to add an assignment or open the gradebook with the following stack trace:

```
Debug info: Column 'grademax' cannot be null
INSERT INTO mdl_grade_items (courseid,categoryid,itemname,itemtype,itemmodule,iteminstance,itemnumber,iteminfo,idnumber,calculation,gradetype,grademax,grademin,scaleid,outcomeid,gradepass,multfactor,plusfactor,aggregationcoef,aggregationcoef2,sortorder,display,decimals,locked,locktime,needsupdate,weightoverride,timecreated,timemodified,hidden) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
[array (
0 => '206',
1 => NULL,
2 => NULL,
3 => 'course',
4 => NULL,
5 => '73',
6 => NULL,
7 => NULL,
8 => NULL,
9 => NULL,
10 => 1,
11 => NULL,
12 => 0,
13 => NULL,
14 => NULL,
15 => 0,
16 => 1,
17 => 0,
18 => 0,
19 => 0,
20 => 1,
21 => 0,
22 => NULL,
23 => 0,
24 => 0,
25 => 1,
26 => 0,
27 => 1474281854,
28 => 1474281854,
29 => 0,
)]
Error code: dmlwriteexception

×Stack trace:

·         line 477 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_write_exception thrown

·         line 1172 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()

·         line 1218 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->insert_record_raw()

·         line 343 of /lib/grade/grade_object.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->insert_record()

·         line 472 of /lib/grade/grade_item.php: call to grade_object->insert()

·         line 2259 of /lib/grade/grade_category.php: call to grade_item->insert()

·         line 2230 of /lib/grade/grade_category.php: call to grade_category->get_grade_item()

·         line 2447 of /lib/grade/grade_category.php: call to grade_category->load_grade_item()

·         line 897 of /lib/gradelib.php: call to grade_category->is_course_category()

·         line 850 of /course/moodleform_mod.php: call to grade_get_categories_menu()

·         line 191 of /mod/assign/mod_form.php: call to moodleform_mod->standard_grading_coursemodule_elements()

·         line 201 of /lib/formslib.php: call to mod_assign_mod_form->definition()

·         line 95 of /course/moodleform_mod.php: call to moodleform->__construct()

·         line 255 of /course/modedit.php: call to moodleform_mod->__construct()

×Output buffer: <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$requiremodintro in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/course/moodleform_mod.php</b> on line <b>894</b><br /> <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$gradepointdefault in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/course/moodleform_mod.php</b> on line <b>814</b><br /> <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$gradepointdefault in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/grade/grade_item.php</b> on line <b>270</b><br /> <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$gradepointdefault in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/grade/grade_item.php</b> on line <b>270</b><br />
```

It does not happen in all courses and I am using Moodle 3.1 on CentOS.

Please, how can I correct this?

Comment: Am not sure, but just concern about the undefined property that appears in the last row. Are you sure that's not creating the issue?

Comment: This is line 894 of that file:  $required = $CFG->requiremodintro;

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert null into the array (at index 11: grademax). The program does not like this. Most likely this is not a nullable field and is likely used for some type of calculation (averages?). I'm not sure what goes in that field, seems like the highest grade in the class or the max number of points. This field needs a value. Seems like it should be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be a null entry into a non nullable field (grademax). Later in the stack dump though, it mentions $requiremodintro and $gradepointdefault as properties that are undefined, which may be due to a config file that is not being loaded prior to the Insert.